# Function Import repeats same row

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am using entity framework to access my data on MSSQL server.  I call a stored procedure via function import.  When I iterate through the rows of returned data, the rows are all the same as the first row.  The correct number of rows is present.  When I execute the stored procedure in Management Studio, the data returned is as expected; 3 unique rows.

Here is my code I use to walk through the data:

```
packprofileModel.packprofileEntities ppe = new packprofileModel.packprofileEntities();
var res = ppe.Resources.Where(r => r.Id.Equals(rid)).SingleOrDefault();
var ats = ppe.ResourceAttributes(res.Id);
ats.ToList().ForEach(a =>
{
     AttributePanel.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = a.Title });
});
```

Thanks for looking at my question.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if the result of the function import is mapped to the entity and the entity doesn't have primary key or the column(s) mapped as key doesn't have unique values. Either fix the problem with mapped key (key must be always unique) or map the result as a complex type instead of an entity.